# AngularJS - How to submit an array of checkbox selections dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, checkbox, binding

I'm building a really simple form with angular. I have an array of objects, like this:

```
data: [{id: 1, name: "Peter"},{id: 2, name: "Paul"}...]
```

And I need to build some checkboxes off of that data. A user can select multiple values. Then, when they hit submit, I should send an array of id numbers off to the DB, formatted like this:

```
{nameIds: [1,2]}
```

And I'm having a hell of a time building that array. I've been following other S.O. examples, but something isn't clicking. This is what I have right now:

```
    <label ng-repeat="name in vm.nameArray">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="name.selected"> {{name.name}}
    </label>
        <button ng-click="vm.submit()" class="btn btn-primary margin-10-tb">NEXT</button>
```

and in my controller:

```
vm.nameArray = response.data.data;
vm.selectedNames = [];
vm.nameIds = [];
vm.submit = function() {
  vm.selectedNames = vm.nameArray.filter(function(name){
    if (name.selected) return name.id;
  });
  vm.selectedNames.forEach(function(name){
    vm.nameIds.push(name.id);
  });
};
```

Maybe you've already guessed, but the issue here is that when a user deselects a name they've previously added, vm.nameIds does not update. The id for the deselected name persists in the array.

Any tips on how to best create this dynamic array for submission would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first search for selected items and finally take its id property:

```
vm.selectedNames = vm.nameArray.filter(function(name){
    return name.selected;
  }).map(function(value){
    return value.id;
  });
```

The data always will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also further reduce the complication if you add "isChecked" property to the data. Please find plunker below:

I have added the logic to add "isChecked" property to the data as well.

Note: Please go with @SergioEscudero's answer if you want to go with your current logic.

http://plnkr.co/edit/f1Eq2OGKTuCLgI6KXn1b?p=preview

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Directive Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <label ng-repeat="name in nameArray">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="name.isChecked"> {{name.name}}
    </label>
        <button ng-click="submitnew()" class="btn btn-primary margin-10-tb">NEXT</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {

$scope.data =  [{id: 1, name: "Peter"},{id: 2, name: "Paul"},
  {id: 3, name: "John"},{id: 4, name: "David"}]

$scope.data.forEach(function(data) {
  //$scope.data[key].isChecked=false;
  data.isChecked=false;
})

$scope.nameArray=$scope.data;

$scope.submitnew = function() {
  $scope.nameArray.forEach(function(data) {
  if(data.isChecked)
  console.log(data.id);
})
}

})
```